# Java Framework in /System/Library and Xcode on Mac

Tags: java, xcode, macos, java-native-interface

I noticed that on my Mac machine(10.10, Xcode 6), I have :

/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/

and

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework

What's the difference between these two? like versions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is part of the system (`/System/Library/Frameworks/`), the other is part of Xcode (`/Applications/Xcode.app`). To be more specific, the path in the Xcode bundle points to the *SDK* so it's the framework Xcode links against. When an that was linked against the framework is running, it's using the system framework.